# Java inheritance, using super()

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, constructor

this part of the assignment is to show inheritance from the java libraries. I have to create a java class that makes a color label set to the appropriate background when called: for instance, if the main says `JLabel colorfulLabel = new JLabel(Color.Blue);` it creates a label with a blue background.

Here's my current code for the colorful label class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class colorfulLabel extends JLabel{
    /*constructor uses one color parameter to represent background color
      creates label using background color
      calls parent constructor using super()
      private Color color;*/
    public colorfulLabel(Color color){
        super(color);

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

ps: Yes it's a small block of code, but I have extreme struggles with GUI's let alone implementing inheritance.

I get an error when trying to invoke the parent constructor.

Comment: Per convention all class names start with an uppercase character. Try adhering to it as soon as possible, it will make your later Java life much easier.

Comment: `"I get an error when trying to invoke the parent constructor."` -- Please always post the entire error message when you're asking about one. Please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're trying to invoke a constructor that doesn't exist, `super(color)`. Please check the [JLabel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) to see what constructors are legal. Why did you want to call this constructor anyway?
2. It makes little sense to create another JLabel inside of your JLabel extended class.
3. You may need to make your object opaque inside of the constructor if you plan on seeing the background color.

Better would be to pass in text, or to mimic other valid JLabel constructors with the addition of a Color parameter:

```
public class ColorLabel extends JLabel {
  public ColorLabel(String text, Color bg) {
    super(text); // **this** super makes sense
    setBackground(bg);
    setOpaque(true);
  }

  // + overloads for other constructors that accept Icon or text and Icon, or 
  // text, Icon and position,....
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm horrid with GUI'S in java. It's at the trial and error phase, but this part of the assignment says as follows:One class named ColorfulLabel - Extends JLabel. The constructor will use one color parameter which represents the bg color of the label. the constructor will create a jlabel object with a specific bg color. Don't forget to call the parent constructor using Super() and then set a bg color. ex: ColorfulLabel blueLabel = new ColorfulLabel(Color.Blue);

Comment: @user3288392: this is not a GUI specific question. It's really little more than a "learn to read the Java API" type of question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// by convention class names should start with an uppercase character
public colorfulLabel(Color color) { character
    super(); // it's not necessary in this case, it's implicit 
    setBackground(color);
}
```

`JLabel` doesn't have a constructor that receives `Color` as a parameter, so that's what's causing the error. Also notice that you don't really need to extend a class for this, you're not adding extra attributes or functionality, a simple call to `setBackground()` over an instance of type `JLabel` does all that you need.

Comment: I only did that because that part of the assignment specified to do so...or so I assumed....it said :One class named ColorfulLabel - Extends JLabel. The constructor will use one color parameter which represents the bg color of the label. the constructor will create a jlabel object with a specific bg color. Don't forget to call the parent constructor using Super() and then set a bg color. ex: ColorfulLabel blueLabel = new ColorfulLabel(Color.Blue)

Comment: @user3288392 ok, that's what my answer above is doing. See the edit